# Postgres having unique Constraint on Array Column And Text Column

Tags: postgresql

```
create table my_table(
id varchar(255) not null primary key,
text_column varchar(255) not null,
array_column text[] not null
);
```

My table state is

```
id|text_column|array_column|
--+-----------+------------+
1 |Abcd       |{a,b}       |
2 |Abcd       |{a}         |
3 |Xyz        |{a,b}       |
```

I would want this to fail

```
insert into my_table values ('4', 'Abcd', '{"b", "a"}');
insert into my_table values ('5', 'Abcd', '{"a", "b"}');
```

I am trying to impose the unique constraint on text_column and array_column.

Array_column is not sorted.

Also is it better way to do?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe, I have updated it. Sorry for incomplete details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create an auxiliary function that sorts the elements of an array and use that in a unique index:

```
CREATE FUNCTION array_sort(anyarray) RETURNS anyarray
   IMMUTABLE LANGUAGE sql AS
'SELECT array_agg(a.e ORDER BY a.e) FROM unnest($1) AS a(e)';

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ON my_table (text_column, array_sort(array_column));
```

Comment: Thank you. I am trying to put sort as trigger, by passing column name. Just may be out of this context, can we pass column names dynamically to sort?

Comment: CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_table_sort_array() RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
DECLARE column_name   text     := TG_ARGV[0];
BEGIN
  NEW.column_name = sort_array(column_name);
  RETURN NEW;
END;
$BODY$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';

Comment: Sure, that should work in a `BEFORE` trigger.

Comment: I tried, giving this error record "new" has no field "column_name". Its not recognizing the column name

Comment: Your trigger is wrong. But it should work in principle. And no, I am not going to fix your trigger in a comment. That is a different question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74686610/postgres-pass-column-name-as-trigger can you please check and help