# Postgres Pass column name as trigger

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to create a trigger on my table that shall sort a column of array. But I want to make it dynamic by passing column name as parameter

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_table_sort_array() RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
DECLARE column_name   text     := TG_ARGV[0];
begin
 EXECUTE format('NEW.$1 = sort_array($1)', column_name);
  RETURN NEW;
END;
$BODY$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';

CREATE TRIGGER my_table_sort_array_trigger
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON my_table
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE my_table_sort_array('array_column');
```

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
    id varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    text_column varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    array_column _text NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT my_table_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

insert into my_table values ('1', 'a', '{b,a}');
```

But this is failing with the given error

```
SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "NEW"
  Where: PL/pgSQL function my_table_sort_array() line 4 at EXECUTE


Error position:
```

Can you please let me know how to achieve that

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do that.

Comment: Yeah, great question. I'll walk around and listen too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are willing to use [plpython3](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpython.html) then the below. I don't know where `sort_array()` is coming from so I used `array_dims()` instead for illustrative purposes:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.my_table_sort_array()
 RETURNS trigger
 LANGUAGE plpython3u
AS $function$
col_name = TD['args'][0]
array_val = TD['new'][col_name]
plan = plpy.prepare("select array_dims($1)", ["text[]"] )
rs = plpy.execute(plan, [array_val])
plpy.notice(rs[0])
$function$
;

insert into my_table values ('1', 'a', '{b,a}');
NOTICE:  {'array_dims': '[1:2]'}
INSERT 0 1
```